# How to prevent the user profile page of a blocked user to show up?

Tags: 7, users

When a user is blocked the (core) user profile is still accessible. I would rather show a message "this user profile has been removed".

I could write an exception into the user-profile.tpl.php. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to implement [hook_user_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.api.php/function/hook_user_view/7) in a custom module.

First create a page which contains your preferred content (e.g. "This user profile has been removed").  Let's call this node/1337 for now.

Secondly, you want something along the lines of the following:

```
function mymodule_user_view($account, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($account->status == '0') {
    drupal_goto('node/1337');
  }
}
```

There are other parameters you can pass to [drupal_goto](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7) if you wish (such as HTTP response code) - check out the API for more info :-)

Comment: Ooh, another note..you might want to put some authentication in for user 1 - as it's written, the code will block user 1 out of the profile as well.  Sorry.

Comment: that's great, thank you. Looks like I can use the same code to hide the admin profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to alter the page callback of user profile page, change the access callback to point to your custom function that determine whether a user is blocked.